# Mysql Query is not giving good performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a fairly simple query in MySQL but it is taking around 170 minutes to execute.

Can anyone help me here? I am tired of applying indexes on various keys but no benefit.

```
Update
    H20_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG L
Join
    TEMP_V_3064446579 T
Using
    ( ZS_AUDIENCE_ID, ZS_SOURCE_OBJECT_ID, ZS_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID )
Set 
    ZS_ACTIVE_PERIOD_END_DT = '2015-08-14 15:05:48', 
    ZS_IS_ACTIVE_PERIOD = False 
Where 
    ZS_IS_ACTIVE_PERIOD = True 
And 
    L.ZS_ADDRESS_ID <> T.ZS_ADDRESS_ID 
And 
    T.ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP > L.ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP;
```

Creates:

```
CREATE TABLE `H20_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG` (
  `ZS_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ZS_AUDIENCE_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ZS_SOURCE_OBJECT_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ZS_INSERT_DT` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ZS_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ZS_ADDRESS_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ZS_ACTIVE_PERIOD_START_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZS_ACTIVE_PERIOD_END_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZS_IS_ACTIVE_PERIOD` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZS_ACTIVE_PRIORITY_PERIOD_START_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZS_ACTIVE_PRIORITY_PERIOD_END_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZS_IS_ACTIVE_PRIORITY_PERIOD` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ZS_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG_ID`),
  KEY `IX_H20_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG` (`ZS_AUDIENCE_ID`,`ZS_SOURCE_OBJECT_ID`,`ZS_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID`,`ZS_ADDRESS_ID`),
  KEY `IX_ADDRESS_ID` (`ZS_ADDRESS_ID`,`ZS_IS_ACTIVE_PERIOD`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22920801 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




CREATE TABLE `TEMP_V_3064446579` (
  `ZS_AUDIENCE_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ZS_SOURCE_OBJECT_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ZS_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ZS_ADDRESS_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP` datetime NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_TEMP_V_3064446579` (`ZS_AUDIENCE_ID`,`ZS_SOURCE_OBJECT_ID`,`ZS_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID`,`ZS_ADDRESS_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Both tables circa 3m records

Comment: Just a wild guess, but have you tried changing the USING to an ON and incorporating the two relevant conditions in the WHERE clause there instead?

Comment: Yes, that didn't help actually.

Comment: are the 1:1 links? meaning there will only be 1 H20_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG record that matches TEMP_V_3064446579?

Comment: My only ideas are to either try running multiple smaller queries (perhaps on ranges of ZS_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG_ID values), or tweaking memory-related server settings.

Comment: `T.ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP > L.ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP;`  seems like it may update hundreds of rows many times over...  the `>` here means if there are 50 records for this association it will update 49 times then 48 more than 47 more then 46 more, then....  However if it's known there can only be 1 > per each record, problem isn't hear...  Does this occur and do you really need to update each one multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE
    `H20_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG` `L`
SET 
    `ZS_ACTIVE_PERIOD_END_DT` = '2015-08-14 15:05:48', 
    `ZS_IS_ACTIVE_PERIOD` = False 
WHERE 
    `ZS_IS_ACTIVE_PERIOD` = True AND
    EXISTS (
            SELECT
                1
            FROM
                `TEMP_V_3064446579` `T`
            WHERE
                `L`.`ZS_ADDRESS_ID` <> `T`.`ZS_ADDRESS_ID` AND
                `T`.`ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP` > `L`.`ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP`
            LIMIT 1
    );
```

Comment: I think you might need to include the `ZS_AUDIENCE_ID`, `ZS_SOURCE_OBJECT_ID`, `ZS_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID` fields in the subquery's WHERE.

Comment: Exist will not work better with MySQL. At least upto MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

(The `ZS_` makes the SQL hard to read; suggest removing it.)

In `TEMP_V_3064446579`, change `UNIQUE` to `PRIMARY`.

Change

```
KEY `IX_H20_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG` (`ZS_AUDIENCE_ID`,`ZS_SOURCE_OBJECT_ID`,
                                   `ZS_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID`,`ZS_ADDRESS_ID`)
```

to

```
KEY `IX_H20_AUDIENCE_ADDRESS_LOG` (`ZS_AUDIENCE_ID`,`ZS_SOURCE_OBJECT_ID`,
                                   `ZS_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID`,`ZS_ADDRESS_ID`,
                                   `ZS_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP`)
```

If you have a new enough version, please provide `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...`.  If not, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` where the `SELECT` is derived from the `UPDATE`, but without the `SET`.